# how to run a service in background and managed by SharedPreferences Settings

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm coding an app, where there is a PrefereceActivity which contains a SwitchPreference that start or stop a service when the user switches on or off it, and it saves the status of the switch in to SharedPreference. 
Then in the MainActivity I registered A On SharedPreferenceChangeListener, which read the status of the switch, then based on the it start or Stop the service.

```
   // This is  the code in MainATY:
        preferences= getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor= preferences.edit();

        preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
               boolean pushNotification= sharedPreferences.getBoolean(MyPreferences.pushNotificationKey,true);
                if (pushNotification)
                {
                    if (!NotificationService.isRunning){
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
                        bindService(i,MainActivity.this,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (NotificationService.isRunning){
                        unbindService(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and this is PreferenceATY code:

```
pushNotification.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {

                pushNotification= (SwitchPreference) preference;
                editor.putBoolean(pushNotificationKey,pushNotification.isChecked());
                if (!editor.commit())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MyPreferences.this, R.string.changes_saved,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work, can you help me?
 One last thing, how can I make Notifications with more than one line of the content?
This is my notification function:

```
 String thingsToDo=new String();
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                thingsToDo+=String.format("%s:  %s: %s  "
                        ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("subject"))
                        ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("typeOfEvent"))
                        ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("what"))
                        );
                thingsToDo+="/n";
            }
            thingsToDo.substring(0,4);


            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon_diary)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.homework_for_tomorrow))
                    .setContentText(thingsToDo);
            mBuilder.setShowWhen(true);

            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,NotificationViewActivity.class);
            Bundle b= new Bundle();
            b.putString("time",time);
            i.putExtra("b",b);
            i.putExtra("time",time);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.small_icon_diary,"Open",PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,i,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the Question about Notification in this way:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon_diary)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.homework_for_tomorrow))
                    .setContentText(thingsToDo)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(thingsTodo));
```